# CSS Files from separate to single one

Tags: html, css

I have 2 CSS Files for few pages, if i put everything just in one css file, my pages does not load the contents of the css file i have deleted, but actually i have moved it into the main css (style.css)

if i keep them separate , the pages load the contents of the 2 css files

Here the example:

http://tommywebdesigner.com/Vision%20General.html - it loads 2 separate css files nav.css and style.css

when i deleted the nav.css file and move the content into one single css file named style.css, the page doesnt read anymore the nav.css content into the style.css

here the example : http://tommywebdesigner.com/Home%20Page.html

Why this happens?

Comment: Both examples, same file `/css/style.css` and missing closing bracket  for `@media (max-width: 979px) {`

Comment: no Vison General loads style.css and nav.css, Home Page.html loads just style.css which actually has the nav.css content too

Comment: what about missing closing bracket for `@media (max-width: 979px) {`

Comment: that was the problem i have put the nav.css content before the 
@media (min-width: 1200px) and now it's loading. Terrible mistake and missing.

Answer (score 0):

For me,
the navigation looks same. What browser you have??
Try delete cache. It sometimes don't load new css style.